# Storing, retrieveing, editing and deleting data

Tags: java, file, variables, netbeans

I am coding a questionbank with netbeans as a school project. I am using a JFrame GUI to enter question data. I need some clever way to store, edit and delete data in some file. I don´t want to use any databases. I already tried solving this with txt files but it is tedious and wont work. I need some option where I can add an entire question to the file and then when I retrieve it retrieve certain parts. The data below is how I tried solving it. I then used a scanner to read the files line by line and stop everytime a "_" is read. Is there any better way to store this. Or can i store this in a 2 dimensional array in the java program itself.If so any help or solution is appreciated

```
Geography_What is England's capital_Berlin_Manchester_Dover_London_D_3
Maths_What is 2+3_7_9_5_6_C_1 
Economics_What is demand_idk_stuff_demand_supply_C_2
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you are asking for. Best way to store information? When you say retrieve certain parts do you mean a specific question or a specific part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you dont want databases or any external files, the only way to "store" information is to create some data structures to do so. The issue with that is they wont persist past the lifetime of the current running application.

Id advise to use some form of external file, or set up a simple sql db. Its easy and will make the project simpler